# Left cosets of the following group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to find the left cosets of the subgroup $H = \{\, \mathrm{id}, \:(1,4),\: (2,3)\,\}$ of $\mathrm{D}_4$ where $\mathrm{id}$ is the identity elements I guess, and the other elements are cycles. I know that a left coset of $H$ containing $a$ is $\{ ah \mid h \in H \}$. But here, how should I choose $a$? Should I choose the cycle $(5, 6)$ and multiply it with the elements of the set? I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: sorry, i forgot to write is you can see now it is D4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completing @Jared's answer, if we write the presentation of $D_4$ as:

$$D_4=\{id,\underbrace{(1~2~3~4)}_{\large \rho_1},\underbrace{(1~3)(2~4)}_{\large \rho_2},\underbrace{(1~2)(3~4)}_{\large \mu_1},\underbrace{(1~4)(2~3)}_{\large \mu_2},\underbrace{(1~3)}_{\large \delta_1},\underbrace{(2~4)}_{\large \delta_2},\underbrace{(1~4~3~2)}_{\large \rho_3}\}$$ then your $H$ is not a subset either. Now if we accept $H$ is as: $$H=\{id,(1~4)(2~3)\}$$ then follow the definition of the coset of $H$ as you noted in the body.

Answer (score 3):

Since the cosets of a group partition it into disjoint subsets of equal size, you can just pick any element $a$ not in $H$ to find a different coset $aH$.  For example, consider the rotation $a=(1243)$.  Then $aH$ consists of the following two elements:
$$a\cdot id=(1243),\;\text{and}\;a\cdot(14)(23)=(1342)$$

Next, choose another element that is not in $H$ or $aH$, and applying the method as above should give you another coset.  Then you're almost finished!